# EF ConnectionString Problem keyword not supported 'metadata'

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, connection-string

```
connectionString="
   metadata=res://*/Database.AttidudeDB.csdl|res://*/Database.AttidudeDB.ssdl|res://*/Database.AttidudeDB.msl;
   Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=.net;Initial Catalog=DB_;User Id=admin;Password=*****;
   application  name=EntityFramework&quot;"
```

providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

I uploaded my Database to sql Server and im getting this erro r 
"keyword not supported 'metdata'
Any one can help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there i solve it after very hard day it was connection string problem
and it lock like this:

```
 <add name="AttitudeUnitDBEntities" 
   connectionString=" metadata=res://*/Database.AttidudeDB.csdl|res://*/Database.AttidudeDB.ssdl|res://*/Database.AttidudeDB.msl;
   provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
   provider connection string=&quot;
   data source=www.net.com;
   initial catalog=DB_A;
   persist security info=True;user id=admin;
   password=********;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
   providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Authentication, all you need is this:

Data Source=[ServerName];Initial Catalog=[DatabaseName];Integrated Security=False;User ID=[UserName];Password=[Password]

For Windows Authentication:

Data Source=[ServerName];Initial Catalog=[DatabaseName];Integrated Security=True;

I have an open source project that comes with a Connection String Builder project in the tools folder if you are interested:

https://github.com/DataJuggler/DataTier.Net

Connection String Builder:

[image]

Comment: the connection string i get it from from hosted site its same as you mentioned but the problem is i getting error keyword not supported 'metdata' and when i remove metadata line shows keyword not supported 'provider'

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know what to suggest other than your hosting provider might be able to help.